# How do the aggregation methods aggregate performance metrics in MLR?

Tags: r, mlr

In `MLR` R package, there are methods to aggregate the parameter tuning model performance metrics, like `train.mean`, `train.sd`, `test.mean`, `test.sd`. I'm wondering how the aggregation process was done.
From my current knowledge, it seemed the aggregation was carried out at the fold level.

Let's say for 10 repeats, 5 fold cross validation, there are totally 10*5 test error estimate, so the standard deviation of the test error is the variation of the 50 estimates.
But what I want is the error estimate at the repeats level, so for each repeat I have a error estimate averaged by the inner 5 fold, and then my desired standard deviation of test error should be the variation of 10 estimate from the 10 repeats.

I'm wondering how this could be done. Is there any way to extract the raw performance metric for each tuning parameter in each resample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there are two aggregation functions that seem to work on the repeat level "testgroup.sd" and "testgroup.mean". From their description in mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/aggregations.html

Answer (score 0):

Correct, aggregation is done at the fold level.

There is no implemented option to aggregate on the repetition level, you have to code that yourself.

We won't add this feature to {mlr} anymore. Please see [this issue](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/issues/190) on how to do it in {mlr3}.

Comment: I found that there are two aggregation functions that seem to work on the repeat level "testgroup.sd" and "testgroup.mean". From their description in https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/aggregations.html

Comment: Oh nice, I wasn't aware of those!

Comment: @Jiahao-AI It is good practice to mark questions as solved on stackexchange sites by ticking the checkmark. You can also add your comment as an answer and mark this as the correct one. Would be great if you could do this for all of your recent questions. Thanks.